# summation of symbolic variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a summation of symbolic variables constructed by,

```
 x =  transpose(sym('x',[1 5]))
```

I thought I could just call `x1` by `x(1)`. Hence I did the following,

```
syms p 
symsum(p^(i)*x(i),i,1,5)
```

Unfortunately I got the following error

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Is there a way to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [`symsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html), the variable for range (`i` in your case should be a symbolic variable). You haven't defined `i` as a symbolic variable and hence it is considered to be the [imaginary unit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) (which is its default builtin definition). It is always wise to avoid the use of [`i`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) and [`j`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/j.html) as variables since these are for imaginary unit in MATLAB.

However fixing just this won't solve all the problems. Apparently indexing a symbolic variable is not allowed in the function definition for `symsum`. To do your intended operation, I would use [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) like this:

```
x =  sym('x', [1 5]);   
syms p;
sum(p.^(1:5) .* x)
```

which gives:

```
ans = 
x5*p^5 + x4*p^4 + x3*p^3 + x2*p^2 + x1*p
```